# Printing content of class type vector

Tags: c++

Explicit template specialization is not working, the template itself works fine.

the specialization of template passes a vector of a class Date as parameter, I can't figure out how to print the individual values of vector

```
template <typename T>
void printVector(const std::vector<T> &vec) {
    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i<< ' ';
}
template <>
void printVector(const std::vector<Date> &vec) {
    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

I get 2 errors:
binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right hand operand of type 'const Date' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
and:
no operator "<<" matches there operands

Comment: You need to provide an appropriate operator overload for `T` in first place.

Comment: Whats the specialization for when both functions do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear: you need to provide an `operator<<` overload for your `Date` class. E.g.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& date) { /* ... */ }
```

Alternatively, you can manually print out the fields of `Date` in your `printVector` overload that takes a `vector<Date>` - this is however a less flexible solution as it couples the logic for printing a `vector` with the one printing a `Date`.